# ONVIF GetSnapshotUri in vb.net

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, soap, onvif

I am writing some software that involves downloading a JPG from the cameras at work.
I have the rest of the software written and working, but to be able to support more cameras, I want to use ONVIF to request a snapshoturi.
I was able to successfully do this using the RESTClient in Firefox, but I am not familiar with writing out SOAP commands\responses in vb.net

The body of the 2 POST commands that I sent the url of the camera (http://192.168.103.39/onvif/device_service) is as follows:

First one gets the Profile Token:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">
   <soap:Body>
      <trt:GetProfiles/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Then I take that Profile Token and put it in the next command where I request a snapshoturi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl"
xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">
  <soap:Body>
    <trt:GetSnapshotUri >     
      <trt:ProfileToken>102c707f-19d0-4a6f-b519-cea65e98c1f2</trt:ProfileToken>
    </trt:GetSnapshotUri>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This returns:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <trt:GetSnapshotUriResponse>
      <trt:MediaUri>
        <tt:Uri>http://192.168.103.39/stw-cgi/video.cgi?msubmenu=snapshot&amp;Profile=2&amp;action=view</tt:Uri>
        <tt:InvalidAfterConnect>false</tt:InvalidAfterConnect>
        <tt:InvalidAfterReboot>false</tt:InvalidAfterReboot>
        <tt:Timeout>PT0H0M0S</tt:Timeout>
      </trt:MediaUri>
    </trt:GetSnapshotUriResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Now if I can programmatically be able to do the same thing in vb.net (or c#), that would be great. I just can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

your question is pretty wide, try to look for answers here:
https://github.com/alexgubanow/yaoc
i have implemented there basic onvif reading, but based on it you understand how to modify it for your needs.